# Bad attname value on pg_attribute

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have 2 postgres DB's with the same table X, and primary key PKEY (i'm not creator of this).
When im looking on it using my client (i try 2 different) or extracting ddl, i got identical source like this:

```
...
CONSTRAINT pkey PRIMARY KEY(column1, column2)
...
```

The problem is what i see in pg_attribute.attname - first DB have correct values (column1 and column2) but the second have column1 and id (?). The rest of data (attnum and other parameters) are identical...It's interesting that column id not exists on this table (X)...maybe one day it existed, but i'm not sure how to check it).
This is a production environment, so recreating index etc it's not easy...Have you met with a similar situation?

comparison method:

```
  select cls.oid,
        nsp.nspname as object_schema,
         cls.relname as object_name, 
         a.attname,
         case cls.relkind
           when 'r' then 'TABLE'
           when 'm' then 'MATERIALIZED_VIEW'
           when 'i' then 'INDEX'
           when 'S' then 'SEQUENCE'
           when 'v' then 'VIEW'
           when 'c' then 'TYPE'
           else cls.relkind::text
         end as type
  from pg_class cls
    join pg_roles rol on rol.oid = cls.relowner
    join pg_namespace nsp on nsp.oid = cls.relnamespace
    join  pg_catalog.pg_attribute a on a.attrelid = cls.oid
    left outer join pg_attrdef ad on (ad.adrelid = cls.oid and ad.adnum = a.attnum)
    left outer join pg_constraint con on cls.oid = con.conrelid
  where nsp.nspname not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
    and nsp.nspname not like 'pg_toast%'
    and a.attnum > 0
    AND NOT a.attisdropped
    and cls.relname like '%my_pkey_real_name%'
    order by 1, 2
```

This query returns 'column1' and 'column2' in attname column on DB1 and 'column1' and 'id' on DB2.
As i wrote - the problem is that the column 'id' don't exists...when i'm extract ddl i'm getting somthing like:

```
ALTER TABLE X
  ADD CONSTRAINT pkey 
    PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2) NOT DEFERRABLE;
```

on both DB's

Comment: So, summing up, are they identical or not? If there was no schema versioning you probably won't be able to check for these columns. What is your real problem?

Comment: You should show the exact queries that led to your observation. Either you have data corruption (unlikely) or you are connecting to a different database than you want to.

Comment: They are not identical. I'm comparing 2 DB's using dblink and as a result i get the difference on this index (because of bad value on pg_attribute.attname). I'm sure i 'm connecting to correct DB's

Comment: So, how exactly are you comparing them? As Laurenz says, could you [edit] your question to show the exact query you're using and the output it gives you? Can you also show the full DDL that your client generated? (I might be wrong, but I thought `pg_attribute` contained the column definitions, not constraints, so would be unrelated to the one line of code you've shown us.)

Comment: i edited my question, thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

So, i know the reason but not a solution :(
Let's create a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE test.test_x (
  id VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pkey PRIMARY KEY(id)
) 
WITH (oids = false);
```

then query pg_class and pg_attribute:

```
select c.oid, c.* from pg_class c where relname = 'pkey'
select * from pg_attribute where attrelid = 854514857
```

the result of second query is:

[image]

next reneme the primary key column:

```
ALTER TABLE test.test_x RENAME COLUMN id TO id_x;
```

the name of this column have changed, ddl is ok, value in pg_class (queried for the table context) is ok (id_x, not id), but in pg_attribute is still the older one:
[image]

i tried reindex this table (or only index) but it didn't help